# Unable to connect via ODBC in Excel (while connection test works fine)

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

Since I don't like reading long questions myself I'll make it quick and dirty:

Starting Point:

- MySQL DB on Server
- Win10 machine with Excel (Office 365)
- ODBC Driver installed
- Test with ODBC connector works fine:
  [image: ODBC Test]

Goal:

- Connecting from Excel to the DB via ODBC

Problem:

- When choosing the DSN, the following error appears:
  [image]

!BUT! I can connect from other workstations just fine (same setup/credentials).

Checklist:

- IP from this (and other workstations) are allowed on the server (and are correct)
- Excel and drivers are all 32 bit (checked on excel 64 with correct driver, same problem)
- Since the connection test is successful, the login credentials are obviously correct

Steps taken in excel:

- open Excel
- choose ODBC:

[image]

- choose saved (and tested) connection and press "ok":
  [image]

No further steps are taken within excel.

What else could I check? What am I missing here?

Comment: It appears that you're somehow passing `esa` as the username when trying to connect from Excel. Without screenshots of all dialogs and explicit detail of each step taken within Excel, it's impossible to advise further. IOW, your question is too short to answer.

Comment: "esa" is the data source name, "excel" is the username. These exact naming options are successful on other machines. I will add to the question every step taken in excel.

Comment: The error message shows that MySQL is receiving `esa` as the username. Double-check that your DSN does not have the wrong username value saved. I'm guessing that your Windows, Excel, and intended ODBC driver are all 64-bit. You *might* have a 32-bit User DSN that's getting in the way of a 64-bit User DSN; best to only use System DSNs on 64-bit Windows, [as discussed here](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin). Be sure to use both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC Administrators (`C:\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe `, respectively) to check.

Comment: This link was golden, the drivers were indeed mixed up with different credentials, even though they should not interfere. You can post this as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shows that MySQL is receiving `esa` as the username. Double-check that your DSN does not have the wrong username value saved.

I'm guessing that your Windows, Excel, and intended ODBC driver are all 64-bit.

You might have a 32-bit User DSN that's getting in the way of a 64-bit User DSN; best to only use System DSNs on 64-bit Windows, [as discussed here](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin).  Be sure to use both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC Administrators (`C:\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`, respectively) to check.